# Keys for udev_device_get_property_value

Tags: c, libudev

What keys (c strings) can be used in udev_device_get_property_value? Where I can look for list of all keys?

It is looks that no chance to find it in official API documentation.

Thanks!

Only founds ref manuals like http://epic-beta.kavli.tudelft.nl/share/gtk-doc/html/libudev/index.html
But there is no about keys